# Capture undefined number of items in Regex

Tags: regex

I want to capture the following data:

[TREND, JOHN, DATA1, 0.17, 33.34, 26, 33.33, 0.25, 33.33, DATA2, 0.26, 20.0, 261, 20.0, 0.234, 20.0, 0.1, 20.0, 5, 20.0, FINAL, 245]

From the following text:

```
Market

#TREND

Person: JOHN

DATA1
1) 0.17 (33.34%) 
2) 26 (33.33%)      
3) 0.25 (33.33%)  
* random text here

DATA2
1) 0.26 (20.0%) 
2) 261 (20.0%) 
3) 0.234 (20.0%) 
4) 0.1 (20.0%) 
5) 5 (20.0%) 
* qsdfdsf random dsfg text random here

FINAL
245

Signature
```

I have written the following Regex code that works properly in this precise example :

```
#(TREND)\n+\w*:\s*(JOHN)\n+(DATA1)\n\d\S\s(\d+.?\d*)\s\((\d+.?\d*)%\)\s*\n\d\S\s(\d+.?\d*)\s\((\d+.?\d*)%\)\s*\n\d\S\s(\d+.?\d*)\s\((\d+.?\d*)%\)\s*\n.*\n*(DATA2)\n\d\S\s(\d+.?\d*)\s\((\d+.?\d*)%\)\s*\n\d\S\s(\d+.?\d*)\s\((\d+.?\d*)%\)\s*\n\d\S\s(\d+.?\d*)\s\((\d+.?\d*)%\)\s*\n\d\S\s(\d+.?\d*)\s\((\d+.?\d*)%\)\s*\n\d\S\s(\d+.?\d*)\s\((\d+.?\d*)%\)\s*\n.*\n*(FINAL)\n(\d+)
```

I would like to make it extentable for random number of item of DATA1 and DATA2 from 1 to 10 items each :

```
Market

#TREND

Person: JOHN

DATA1
1) 0.17 (33.34%) 
2) 26 (33.33%)      
3) 0.25 (33.33%) 
4) 0.11 (40.40%)
5) 0.222 (50.50%) 
* random text here

DATA2
1) 0.26 (20.0%) 
2) 261 (20.0%) 
3) 0.234 (20.0%) 
* qsdfdsf random dsfg text random here

FINAL
245

Signature
```

Comment: This appears to be an odd case for a regex, do you have no option to use some code for that and avoid doing everything in the regex? Also, what type/dialect of regex do you use?

Comment: Thanks ArSeN. Yes I'll probably end coding the stuff. I just start in Regex, doing tests on regex101.com.